# Monitoring Slow Traces with OpenTelemetry and Jaeger

Tags: java, trace, open-telemetry, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I'm using manual instrumentation with OpenTelemetry and Jaeger to view traces from a Java application.
I want to set up monitoring and alerts for traces that take longer than 1 minute.
What are the steps to achieve that?

Thanks!